# Prototype: How to filter result set, like jQuery?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, css-selectors

#### jQuery

---

allows something like:

```
var divs = jQuery('div');
jQuery('a', divs);
```

#### Prototype

---

[docs](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) say:

```
$$('#navbar a', '#sidebar a');
// -> all links within the elements of ID "navbar" or "sidebar"
```

Which I took to mean that it is performing the same thing as this in jQuery: `jQuery('#navbar a, $sidebar a');`

---

So I guess the question is what should the marked line be:

```
var divs = $$('div');
var inner_spans = $$('span', divs); // * marked line
```

Comment: in jQuery you'd use .find() to filter. in Prototype you'd use .select()   See: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/select/

Comment: @Diodeus I just found select and was going to come here to close/answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`select` function](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/select/) as [Diodeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12579/diodeus) listed, is what I think I was after.

```
var divs  = $$('div');
var spans = [];
divs.each(function(div){
   spans.push(div.select('span'));
});
```

Really, the only bit I cared about was the `div.select('span')`, pushing them into an array wasn't really the goal here :)

Answer (score 0):

So you're just looking for `span`s that are children of `div`s right? Can't you just:

```
var inner_spans = $$('div span');
```

Comment: no, if I wanted that, I would have just used that :)  I'm trying to do with Mathias said, search/find within the context of other elements.

Comment: @vol7ron - Well, the above does "search/find" `span`s within the context of `div`s. But I agree it's of limited value if you have complex selectors or if your initial context is already captured as a set of elements & not just a selector.

Comment: I don't think I ever got back to you.  I think the spans may have been deeply nested.  Would your method work for that?